# How can I get an asynchronous service call to update the view when it returns in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a follow up to my [previous AngularJS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966252/how-does-the-resource-get-function-work-synchronously-in-angularjs).

I am trying to replicate the functionality of the $resource service that is mentioned in this video tutorial: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRelx4-ISbs).

In this tutorial, it is shown that you can update a scope variable and its view using an asynchronous call.  First, here's the resource that's set up:

```
$scope.twitter = $resource('http://twitter.com/:action',
    {action: 'search.json', q: 'angularjs', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
    {get: {method: 'JSONP'}});
```

Then the `get` function is called on the resource to make the ajax call and update the necessary scope variable:

```
$scope.twitterResult = $scope.twitter.get();
```

What's happening here is that `$scope.twitter.get()` immediately returns an empty object reference.  Then, when the ajax request returns, that object is updated with the data from Twitter.  The view then updates all {{twitterResult}} instances and you see the data that was returned.

What I don't get is, when the object is updated in the asynchronous callback, how does the scope know that the value has changed?

I don't think it does - the callback must call some kind of update function on the scope, right?  But if so, how is this done?  I have heard of a function called `$apply` that might be the answer - but how do you reference $scope.$apply() from inside the resource?

I have created a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Qcz5Y/10/

(Edit: Here is a newer JSFiddle with a different async call to illustrate the problem using an ajax call instead of setTimeout: http://jsfiddle.net/Qcz5Y/14/)

In this example, you will see a controller and a resource. The controller's scope has a property, `fruit`, which starts out set to an object.  When you click 'Get new fruit', that property is set to `fruitResource.get()`, which immediately returns an empty object.  It then makes an asynchronous call, and finally executes a callback which updates the value of the object that was originally returned.

When this happens, the value of `$scope.fruit` is properly updated to what was set in the callback. But it isn't reflected in the view.

If you click "Print current fruit", it will log to the console the current value of `$scope.fruit`.  This was just for checking; it has the side-effect of updating the view.

I feel like I need to be doing something like $scope.$apply() at the bottom of the `get_callback` function (you'll see it in the code). Would that be the right thing to do?  If so, how do I get a reference to $scope inside the fruitResource?  I know I can probably pass `$scope` into `fruitResource.get()` as a parameter and then reference it that way, but the $resource.get() function in the example mentioned at the top doesn't need to do this, so I was hoping that AngularJS provides some way to get the scope from services automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out that you can pass `$rootScope` into a service and then call `$apply` on that.  So when you want to update your view, you just do `$rootScope.$apply()`.

Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qcz5Y/11/

Comment: your own answer is not correct: you need to use $rootScope.$apply only because you are using JavaScript setTimeout method instead of AngularJS $tiemout service.

Comment: Your correction is not correct.  Please see my comment on your solution. I am open to the possibility of other solutions, but `$timeout` is not the answer.

Comment: $http will behave like a $timeout (!) so doing async call via $http (or any other mechanism provided by angular) will not need $apply. The bottom line is this: you need to call $apply when doing calls from "outside" of angular.

Comment: Again, an ajax call is just an example.  The real use case I have in mind is using indexeddb.  As far as I know, indexeddb does not have a wrapper provided by angular like XHRs do with `$http`.  So yes, it would be outside of angular, and it would require `$rootScope.$apply()`. That is the only generalized solution, which is what I was looking for.  I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear that you are trying to do a call without using angular services. I just wanted to make it clear that calling $apply is _not_ mandatory to have Resource-like behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Actually simulating behavior of Resource is quite simple and boils down to doing async call and returning an empty results immediately. Then, when data do arrive from the server a returned reference needs to be updated. Here is the example using your use-case:

```
   get: function() {
        var fruit = {};

        // Asynchronous call that executes a callback. Simulation of ajax/db request            
        $timeout(function() {
            fruit.type = ['banana', 'strawberry', 'watermellon', 'grape'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
            fruit.count = [1, 2, 3, 4][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
        }, 2000);

        return fruit;
    }
```

Here is the complete jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/sBgAT/1/

Please note that I'm using angular's $timeout service to simulate async call since $timeout will take care of calling $apply when it is needed and thus will trigger UI re-paint without any manual intervention. You were bumping into issues since you were trying to use setTimout that needs a call to $apply.

Comment: No, that is not correct because you are misunderstanding the problem.  The use of setTimeout in my JSFiddle is only an example to simulate something like an ajax call.  An ajax call would not use setTimeout, so it could not simply be replaced with $timeout. I was looking for a generalized solution to asynchronous calls, not setTimeout specifically.  So using `$rootScope.$apply()` is correct, unless there is an even better solution that is not using `$timeout`