# AngularJS : factory $http service

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

I am trying to understand the concept of factory and service in Angular. I have the following code under the controller

```
init();

    function init(){
        $http.post('/services', { 
            type : 'getSource',
            ID    : 'TP001'
        }).
        success(function(data, status) {
            updateData(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {

        });

        console.log(contentVariable);
    };
    function updateData(data){
        console.log(data);
    };
```

This code works fine. But when i move $http service into factory, i am not able to return data back to controller.

```
studentApp.factory('studentSessionFactory', function($http){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getSessions = function(){
        $http.post('/services', { 
            type : 'getSource',
            ID    : 'TP001'
        }).
        success(function(data, status) {
            return data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {

        });
    };
    return factory;
});

studentApp.controller('studentMenu',function($scope, studentSessionFactory){
    $scope.variableName = [];
    init();
    function init(){
        $scope.variableName = studentSessionFactory.getSessions();
        console.log($scope.variableName);
    };
});
```

Is there any advantage to using factory, since $http works even under controller

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The purpose of moving your `studentSessions` service out of your controller is to achieve separation of concerns.  Your service's job is to know how to talk with the server and the controller's job is to translate between view data and server data.

But you are confusing your asynchronous handlers and what is returning what.  The controller still needs to tell the service what to do when the data is received later...

```
studentApp.factory('studentSession', function($http){
    return {
        getSessions: function() {
            return $http.post('/services', { 
                type : 'getSource',
                ID    : 'TP001'
            });
        }
    };
});

studentApp.controller('studentMenu',function($scope, studentSession){
    $scope.variableName = [];

    var handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
        $scope.variableName = data;
        console.log($scope.variableName);
    };

    studentSession.getSessions().success(handleSuccess);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Makes sense now. I get a `missing } error after property list` error. Error persists after closing adding a close paranthesis for return in factory.

Comment: Oki fixed the paranthesis part. Now the code is `studentApp.factory('studentSession', function($http){
    return {
        getSessions: function() {   
            return $http.post('/services', { 
                type : 'getSource',
                ID    : 'TP001'
            });
        }
    }
});`  Now got an error stating `Error b is not a function`. I dont have any function called b. Any suggestion on what triggers this error?

Comment: Thanks.  I missed that brace.  As for the "b is not a function", are you using some sort of code minification or uglification?

Comment: Im using minified angularjs. will try out changing to normal version. thnx

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this... exactly the concept I've been trying to get my head around.

Comment: @de-bugged You were getting that error because the dependencies here are Implicity. In their documentation it's says to avoid it because it bugs with minificator/obsfucators. [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Im not using any minification tools and it also throws that get is not a function. When I console log it it shows that it was not returned as object with a function but just a function

Answer (score 10):

The first answer is great but maybe you can understand this:

```
studentApp.factory('studentSessionFactory', function($http){
    var factory = {};

    factory.getSessions = function(){
        return $http.post('/services', {type :'getSource',ID :'TP001'});
    };

    return factory;
});
```

Then:

```
studentApp.controller('studentMenu',function($scope, studentSessionFactory){
      $scope.variableName = [];

      init();

      function init(){
          studentSessionFactory.getSessions().success(function(data, status){
              $scope.variableName = data;
          });
          console.log($scope.variableName);
     };
 });
```

Comment: Looks like a good answer, but `.success` has now been deprecated it seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531336/angularjs-error-success-is-not-a-function#33531521.