# Get data before page load in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to fetch a drop downlist before the page load using angular $http. I tried few combinations but it keep on giving the same error:

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: officeListProvider <- officeList <- myController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=officeListProvider%20%3C-%20officeList%20%3C-%20myController**

I am few weeks old in angular so please pardon in case of any silly mistakes.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider.when('../../home/goEeUpdateAngular.obj', {
        templateUrl: '/employee_update_angular.jsp', 
        controller: 'myController',
        resolve: {
            officeList: function(officeListFactory) {
                return officeListFactory.getOfficeList();
            }
        }
    });   
}]);

myApp.factory('officeListFactory', function($http, $window) {
    $window.alert("Hi");
    var factoryResult = {
        getOfficeList: function() {
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url: '../../home/goOfficesList.obj' 
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log (data);
                return data;
            });

            return promise;
        }
    }; 

    console.log (factoryResult.getOfficeList());
    return factoryResult;
});

myApp.controller('myController',function ($scope,officeList) {
    $scope.officeListFactory = officeListFactory.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller you should call only officeList. Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/jx8aho3h/2/). I too sample webapi instead of your url

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider.when('../../home/goEeUpdateAngular.obj', {
        templateUrl: '/employee_update_angular.jsp', 
        controller: 'myController',
        resolve: {
            officeList: function(officeListFactory) {
                return officeListFactory.getOfficeList();
            }
        }
    });   
}]);

myApp.factory('officeListFactory', function($http, $window) {
    $window.alert("Hi");
    var factoryResult = {
        getOfficeList: function() {
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url: '../../home/goOfficesList.obj' 
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log (data);
                return data;
            });

            return promise;
        }
    }; 

    console.log (factoryResult.getOfficeList());
    return factoryResult;
});

myApp.controller('myController',function ($scope,officeList) {
    $scope.officeListFactory = officeList.data; //changes are made here
});
```

Comment: Happy to help always.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "officeListProvider" is not present or not visible, you need to add it as dependency.

Please try the below change:

```
var ctrl = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
```

to

```
var ctrl = angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services']);
```

and also please use the same service name it is either srvOfficeList or officeList, and also check your service factory, it is not right - example:[AngularJS : factory $http service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227644/angularjs-factory-http-service)

Hope it will fix the issue.

Please try to create a CodePen (or similar tool) while posting the question, so that the Answer can tried/fixed in there and shared back with you.

Comment: Thanks Surya, based on your suggestions, I updated the code. Now the 
console.log (data) [see above], prints the 1850 records as expected but how should I hook it up to $routeProvider.resolve() method. I want to load the drop down before the page initialize.

Comment: load the drop down before the page initialises? what do you mean? the data is in client-side javascript and you need to import that into your html using AngularJS Controller - how to load data from resolve to controller, check this: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: I want to get data from database before page load in angular. Please see the URL below.
http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-data-page-load-angular.

Comment: I used the URL u mentioned , they use like -   resolve: {
            message:...................................... and than inject the same in controller  app.controller("newsController", function (message).
See here name "message" is same in controller and routerProvider function but when I did the same [see the code i just updated] the injector service not able to recognize the  provider.This is the error I get :                                  
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: officeListProvider <- officeList <- myController