# AngularJS error .success is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I have build a factory to handle the functions for my controller, but somehow the controller returns an error on one of the functions:

> Error: Auth.getUser(...).success is not a function
>   @http://localhost:8080/app/controllers/mainCtrl.js:10:1
>   ...

I have no idea what's going on here, the rest of the functions seem to be working fine?

main controller:

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])
.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
        Auth.getUser()
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.user = data;
            });
    });
    vm.doLogin = function() {
        Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
            .success(function(data) {
                $location.path('/users');
            });
    };
});
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: AngularJS v1.4.7, just installed angular with bower

Comment: you should rather use the .then() function. you can pass it 2 functions as arguments, the first one for the success callback (same as .success) and the second one for the error callback.

Comment: $q.reject() would return a promise that doesn't have a success method, wouldn't it? even in legacy versions?

Comment: Your question has a lot of views and is the first google results for this error message. Therefore I think it could be drastically edited by removing all the code and just asking about the error message.   But I don't want to make such a big edit to your post without asking first (also I'm an angular newbie so I might be wrong). Do you agree?

Comment: Sure, go ahead and clean up the question to whatever seems logical to you. Just be sure to keep the relevant promise methods

Comment: I faced the similar issue while adding service to a controller (Dependency Injection). Then I tried .then 'promise' with syntax like below: $http.get('/products.json').then( function(response){ ... }, function(errResponse){ console.log('Error Found') } ); Seems like .success has deprecated.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

See '**Deprecation Notice**' from [$http service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http legacy promise methods *success* and *error* have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard *then* method instead.

You can learn more about these methods in the [documentation about $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Answer (score 21):

Here it is the code

**Depricated code**

```
$http(  
{  
    method: 'POST',  
    url: '/Home/CreateCustomer',   /*You URL to post*/
    data: $scope.cust   /*You data object/class to post*/
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config)  
{  

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config)  
{  

});
```

**Allowed code**  [Angular $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http(
    {
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/Home/CreateCustomer',  /*You URL to post*/
       data: $scope.cust  /*You data object/class to post*/
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       // this callback will be called asynchronously
       // when the response is available


    }, function errorCallback(response) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can use then instate success:

```
var personController = function ($scope, personService) {
    $scope.persons = personService.getAll().then(function (data) {
        $scope.persons = genericSuccess(data);
    });
    var genericSuccess=function(res) {
        return res.data;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a good thing that **.success is deprecated** anyways. I personally never made peace with it, reason you ask ?

```
object.functionCall(parameters).success(functions (response){

if(response!=="failure")
do this-----
});
```

I mean what kind of success deal with failure inside its block.
Use **then** instead and all logic will start to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

success promise is deprecated now. Use then function instead success

Answer (score 0):

angular version 1.2.x you can use .success 
angular version 1.6.x you will get error " .success is not a function"

solution is:  replace ".success" with ".then"