# jQuery Ajax request turn into AngularJS $http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, jsonp

I have such jQuery Ajax request. I need to turn it into an AngularJS $http request. How can I do that?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: false,
        data:{
            user: username,
            pass: password
        },
        beforeSend: function (request){
            request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", languageCode);
        },
        url: someUrl
    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus){
       console.log("failed");
    });
```

**My Angular Implementations**

Response {"data" : "", "status" : "200", "config" : .... } Data is empty

```
login : function (username, password) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: someUrl,
    data: {
      user: username,
      pass: password
    },
    headers: {
      'Accept-Language': languageCode
    }
  })
}
```

I succeeded to get data wrapped in JSON_CALLBACK with next request. But I don't know how to call that callback. It is not done automatically. Response looks like {data:"JSON_CALLBACK({mydata})"...}

```
login : function (username, password) {
  var url = someUrl
    + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&user=' + username
    + '&pass=' + password;

  return $http.post(url);
},
```

Comment: Easy: $http service.

Comment: Yes, I tried $http service, I tried different variations of requests. I succeeded few times to get response using $http.get/$http.post requests but they were wrapped in JSON_CALLBACK. How could I get data from that callback? It is not reachable from .success .error .

Request implementation above is not mine, I just need to do the same with angular.

Comment: Use $http service to make JSONP request.

Comment: I get undefined data everytime I use $http.jsonp()
Maybe it is a server bug ? I find request above strange, but it works

Comment: You didn't post your code, and still you expect answer to your problem? I'm pretty sure you are doing something wrong, so it doesn't work. But who knows without seeing your code (angular version).

Comment: Oh, sure, thanks. I updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a JSONP POST request. When jQuery sees `dataType: jsonp`, it ignores the `method` propery and uses a script GET request. The data is added as parameters of the URL.

In AngularJS, JSONP requests are specified with `method: 'JSONP`. The callback parameter needs to be `JSON_CALLBACK` and must be capitalized.

```
login : function (username, password) {
  return $http({
    //method: 'POST',
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: someUrl,
    //data: {
    params: {
      user: username,
      pass: password,
      callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
    },
    headers: {
      'Accept-Language': languageCode
    }
  })
}
```

Be aware that since the data is sent as URL parameters, sensitive information such as passwords are vulnerable to snooping attacks.

---

To demonstrate on JSFiddle:

```
var url="//jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/";
var params = { user: "myUser",
               pass: "123456",
               callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
            };
$http.jsonp(url, { params: params} )
    .then(function onSuccess(response) {
         $scope.response = response;
         console.log(response);
    })
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btoj6nhq/).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation.  but here is somewhat counterpart for that jquery request

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl',
  data: {  
        user: username,
        pass: password 
  },
  headers: {
    'Accept-Language':languageCode
  }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //do something
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    //do something
  });
```

Comment: I tried  this kind of request, I get successful response, but data inside it is empty, ( data : " " ). When I add following parameter for jsonp requests: "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK" I get data wrapped in this callback, looks something like: 
response: {data : "JSON_CALLBACK({here is data I need})", ..}

Comment: ok maybe add this `responseType:'json'` on the parameter and try it

Comment: still same result :(

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS error .success is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531336/angularjs-error-success-is-not-a-function)

Might have something to do with it??

What API are you working with?