# angular $http.get() function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

i am new to angularjs.can somebody help me to get this fixed.

**Code**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('angCon2', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nlfmz')
                .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.lists = response;
                });
    });
```

**Error Message**

> TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICgnr.png)

Comment: What gave you the idea that `.success` is a thing…? → https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Use `then` instead of `success`, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531336/angularjs-error-success-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try with

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('angCon2', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nlfmz')
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.lists = response;
                });
    });
```

So use then instead of success

Comment: can you give me a rating? :-)

Comment: ya sure i ll do