# Why my AngularJS ajax auto fire eventhough I don't call it?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, spring-security

In my application, I want to fire an ajax call when ng-click event occur :

```
<ul class="sub">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;"  ng-class="{active : isSet(1)}" ng-click="getData(); setTab(1)">Bla bla bla</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my script :

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['smart-table'])
            .controller('TabController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http)
            {
                $scope.tab = 2;

                $scope.setTab = function (newTab)
                {
                    $scope.tab = newTab;
                };

                $scope.isSet = function (tabNum)
                {
                    return $scope.tab === tabNum;
                };

                $scope.getData = function ()
                {
                    $http({
                        url: "/goodsList",
                        method: "GET"
                    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config)
                    {
                        angular.copy(data, $scope.oriList);
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config)
                    {
                        alert('Error getting data');
                    });
                };
            }]);
```

When i debug my script on IntelliJ, it it stop on login section, and the response is the userinfo (which is the response of spring sercurity service). There is no line of code that fire the ajax call except the li tag.

1. Why my ajax fire right after spring security service?
2. In addition, after login to home page, i click the li tag but ajax call doesn't fire, because the debugger doesn't stop at the break point. What mistake did I make?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solve! After look at browser console output as Sateesh Kumar said, the console say : $http(...).success is not a function, and I change my ajax function like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531336) and it work

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***

JS

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
                .controller('TabController', ['$scope','$http' ,function ($scope, $http)
                {
                    $scope.tab = 2;

                    $scope.setTab = function (newTab)
                    {
                        $scope.tab = newTab;
                    };

                    $scope.isSet = function (tabNum)
                    {
                        return $scope.tab === tabNum;
                    };


                    $scope.getData = function(){

                         $http({
                             url: "/goodsList",
                             method: "GET"
                        }).then(function(response){
                             angular.copy(data, $scope.oriList);
                         } , function(response){
                             alert('Error getting data');
                         });
                    }

                    $scope.s = function(){
                        alert("AXX");
                    }
                }]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="mainApp" >
<div ng-controller="TabController">
    <ul class="sub">
    <li>
        <button   ng-class="{active : isSet(1)}" ng-click="getData(); setTab(1)">Bla bla bla</button>
        <button ng-click="s()">
            omri lugasi
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I add '$http' but nothing change

Comment: sec put fiddle @hai_uit

Comment: fix my answer look on getData function @hai_uit