# FileSaver.js doesn't download PDF with Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, filesaver.js

I have an issue with [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), I can not download a PDF (or PNG or excel file) on Safari, but it works on any other web browser. I get the error in the console : 'Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.'

What is weird is that, this PDF file doesn't get downloaded if Tomcat serves it, but if it is Apache that serves the file, the download works fine.

Here is a sample of code (I am working with angular 1.5.8):

```
$http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .success(function (response) {
                var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                fileSaverService(file, filename);
            });
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug with safari. Have you tried a work-around with saveAs? `var blob = new Blob([response], {type:"application/octet-stream"})
    saveAs(blob, "mypdf.pdf") `

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

Comment: @Vivz your answer is totally useless here, but thank you anyway. As specified in my post, I am using angular 1.5.8, and methods success and error have been deprecated in angular 1.6

Comment: @Mouss I reffered this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531336/angularjs-error-success-is-not-a-function and here the OP is using angular version lower than yours and .then did the work for him. So I thought it might be related to that.

Comment: @zer02: I mistook my test, I have done it on Chrome not in Safari, it still doesn't work on Safari :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I was using axios to make a call (it was post request in my case) to the download service. The code below worked for me:

```
axios.post(url, downloadRequest, {responseType:'blob'})
    .then(response =>{              
        var filename = 'example.zip';
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type:"application/octet-stream"});
        saveAs(blob , filename);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue with base64,Pdf was not able to open.
This i have resolved converting base64 to bin and than converted into **Uint8Array(byteNumbers)**.
Check below snippet which has worked for me.

```
const byteCharacters = atob(b64);
const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
   byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/pdf"});
saveAs(blob, "sample.pdf");
```