# Cannot read property 'success' of undefined when mocking a promise in selenium-karma test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am working on an Angular project and in a js dialog file, I have a server-call which is used to save the detail. And most importantly it won't return anything (void) to the client side.

```
ServerService.methodName(param1, param2).success(handleSuccessFunc).error(handleErrorFunc);
```

There is a selenium-karma test file for this and I need this method to be mocked in the test file. Since the method returns a promise, this method is mocked within the beforeEach function

```
    beforeEach(function () {
         spyOn(ServerService, 'methodName').and.callFake(function () {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               deferred.promise.success = function (successCallback) {
                   deferred.promise.then(function (result) {
                       successCallback(result);
                   });

                   return deferred.promise;
               };
           });
    }
```

the test case is updated as below

```
 it('test case for the save method', function () {
            // test assertion stuff 
      expect(ServerService.methodName).toHaveBeenCalledWith(param1, param2);

});
```

but still there is an error when executing the test case saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
        at <Jasmine>
```

it simply means that the mocking of `ServerService.methodName(param1, param2)` returns an undefined and the success call of undefined is trying to be executed.

Am I doing anything wrong when mocking ? Any ideas to solve this issue

Comment: Can't your fake service method just return `$q.resolve()` instead? It looks like you're trying to mock promise functionality when you shouldn't need to.

Comment: when i do this, it says "TypeError: ServerService.MethodName(...).success is not a function"

Comment: What angularjs version are you using? The promise functions `success` and `error` have been deprecated for a while now. Use `then` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS error .success is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531336/angularjs-error-success-is-not-a-function)