# Using globals in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, global-variables

I am trying to use global variables from one file in another file. I have it working from the original file(controller.js) into the html file but I cant not get it working from the controller.js to the service.js.

I am rather new at angular and trying to figure this out.

Comment: Without code and a clear description of the problem, it's impossible to answer. But you should not do that anyway. globals are evil. Use what Angular provides to share information between components: services.

Comment: I know globals are evil. I try to avoid them at all cost. But what I am trying to do is call a function from the server and based on the information that I get back I want to show or hide some ion-item. I am using ng-show to get it working from the Controller.js file but I would like to call the function from services.js. What is the best way to accomplish this with out globals

Comment: From the angularJS tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: Or a more succinct example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16227770/4682556

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to declare a variable in your controller so that your service can write data to that variable. You need to think about it the other way around, passing the service to your controller through dependency injection

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, myServiceIsNowInjected){

})
```

and then calling a method on that service in the controller:

```
myServiceIsNowInjected.getDataFromServer('my param');
```

You will then encounter the problem that getting data from a server is asynchronous, so you need use angular promises so that you can assign the result to a variable on your scope when the data is received. The above, still in your controller will become:

```
myServiceIsNowInjected.getDataFromServer('my param').then(function(data){
  $scope.viewvar = data;       
}, function(err){ console.log(err) });
```

In this way, rather than passing a global variable to the service for the service to write the data to that variable, instead you ask the service to perform some task, and have the controller write the result of that task to the $scope, making it available to the view.

A full solution example of exactly this is available as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227770/4682556).

`$rootScope` should *not* be used for this kind of thing - it will cause you problems as your application grows, whereas using modular controllers which pull information from services will not.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the $rootScope.

In a controller you define:

```
$rootScope.variable = 'your value';
```

And then, in a service or another controller you use it:

```
Console.log($rootScope.variable);
```

Remember inject the $rootScope (like you make with $scope) in the controllers/services definition.

Comment: when you say to inject you  mean something like this   function GetWebsiteSetting($scope, resp, $rootScope){

Comment: Where you define the controller:

angular.module('app.controllers', [])
     
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, **$rootScope**) {
...
});

Comment: ok yes I have done this. my controller looks like this now. .controller("StartpageCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope){
    $scope.showstartCard = true;
    $rootScope.variable = "your variable";
}); and in my service side it is saying cant find variable of undefined

Comment: Are you defining the controller before the service? Pay attention to the order!

Comment: I just checked my order by setting up 2 break points and the contoller.js is being hit first. I alsot did this function Failed($scope, resp, $rootScope){
              $rootScope.variable = false;
              console.log("Get Website Setting Failed: " + $rootScope.variable);
            }  and it still is returning variable is undefined.

Comment: Could you show me your code? Service and controller definitions.