# Angular $http call to synchronous

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, synchronous

```
angular.module('sample').factory('Service',
function( $rootScope, $http, $location )
{
    return {
        loadInfo: function()
        {
            var _url = 'url';
            $http.get( _url )
                .success( function( data )
                {


                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error( function( response )
                {
                    error( response );
                });
        },
});
```

I cannot call any other services without getting this result , but as it is asynchronous in weak networks it is getting time to load this results and end up with errors .
How can i make this call to synchronous. Idea is other all services should wait until it loaded. In jquery ajax we can set a true or false very easily.But i am not able to do it in angular ,I refereed some other answers also but nothing seems to working .

Please suggest

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of angular promises. [Documentation on $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
angular.module('sample').factory('Service',
['$rootScope','$http','$location','$q',function( $rootScope, $http, $location,$q )
{
    return {
        loadInfo: function()
        {
            var _url = 'url';
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get( _url )
                .success( function( data )
                {

                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error( function( response )
                {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                    error( response );
                });
        },
});
```

In your Controller it will look like this then:

```
Service.loadInfo.then(
     function(data){
         //Whatever you want to do with the data  on success     
     }
    ,function(data){
         //Whatever you want to do on error
     }
 );
```

Comment: Thank you , but i am getting Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: I have corrected the syntax now it should not be defined @prash..Hope you injected the service though

Comment: no , i am still checking , i may missing some simple thing :(

Comment: It would be good if you can create a simple plunker of the code that you have so that we can also help you get rid of the problem, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**,

I have added $q service and some resolves and defers. Please check the updated answer.

It would have been really helpful if you could provide us with more code

You made a very simple error in your code

```
angular.module('sample').factory('Service',
function( $rootScope, $http, $location,$q )
{
    return {
        loadInfo: function()
        {
            var _url = 'url';
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            return $http.get( _url )
                .success( function( data )
                {

                    console.log(data);
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error( function( response )
                {
                    error( response );
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
        },
});
```

**Edit**
In order to access 'then' , you need to return a promise, which I created using $q.defer() and returning deferred.resolve().

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: still i am getting same error with out "then " i am getting result

Comment: I have edited my answer, I have added $q service and made use of promises. Hopefully it will work this time, if it doesn't I will try again.

Comment: It is already resolved , thanks @adib for your quick response