# $scope variable has no content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I had controller and function getData as shown. The problem is that the $scope.results outside the for loop has no content. While inside the second http.get request, It has content.

```
appControllers.controller('MyaSellerOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Order', '$http',
    function($scope, $rootScope, Order, $http) {
        $scope.results = [];
        $scope.getData = function() {
               $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + $rootScope.user.user_id).success(function(data){
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + data[i].business_id).success(function(data1){
                             // console.log(data1);        
                             $scope.results[i] = data1;
                       });
                     }
                     console.log($scope.results);
                });
         };
         $scope.getData();
     }]);
```

Comment: that because ajax work asynchronously

Comment: Also, did you unwrap promises? And finally, $http should really go into a separate angular service, that would follow good practie and ease you out of some of the trouble.

Comment: I am newbee to angularjs. SO how will I do to make this work

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

```
// STEP 1: your first request
 $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + $rootScope.user.user_id).success(function(data){
    // STEP 2 : your loop started
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         // STEP 3 : you hit another request. it does not block any operation because it run asynchronously.
         // it also does not wait for any previous request to be completed.
        $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + data[i].business_id).success(function(data1){
             // console.log(data1);
             $scope.results[i] = data1;
       });
     }
     // STEP 4: this doesn't wait for STEP 3 to complete because it [STEP 3 ] run asynchronously.
     // this lin run after for loop complete.
     console.log($scope.results); // so you get nothing here as STEP 3 is still running
});
```

Reference

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests
2. [How to $http Synchronous call with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs)

Comment: so how will I modify this code so that i get the content in $scope variable..?

Comment: try using a service and return a promise from it. On resolution of promise, populate data into `$scope` variable.

Comment: check this out http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/