# Handling AJAX in nested loop (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise

```
var    $scope.units = [1,2];
var  $scope.shiftplans = ['plan1','plan2','plan3']

         for(var i=0;i<$scope.units.length;i++){            
          for(var a=0;a<$scope.shiftplans.length;a++)  {
            console.log('i:'+i);
            console.log('a:'+a);
         } 
        }
```

prints :

> ```
> i:0
> a:0
>
> i:0
> a:1
>
> i:0
> a:2
>
> i:1
> a:0
>
> i:1
> a:1
>
> i:1
> a:2
> ```

but :

```
var    $scope.units = [1,2];
    var  $scope.shiftplans = ['plan1','plan2','plan3']

  for(var i=0;i<$scope.units.length;i++){            
     for(var a=0;a<$scope.shiftplans.length;a++)  {
       ***$http.get(function(){
               console.log('i:'+i);
               console.log('a:'+a);
       });***

     } 
 }
```

Console log in above ajax prints values in different values based on ajax response.

**how to handle AJAX to complete and later to move to looping ?**

Comment: What does this mean: _"how to handle AJAX to complete and later to move to looping"_

Comment: @Satpal Yes, so make sure to use plenty of XML with it. ;-P

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: yes @JLRishe, thats what want (i.e) i will be passing inputs to that ajax call based on the nested loops data. So for each iteration data will change as per loop. But in my current scenario loops are completed before my ajax response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bound the value of `i` and `a` on a [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) for each ajax call, because ajax calls are async, unlike the for-loop

**example:**

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.units.length;i++){            
 for(var a=0;a<$scope.shiftplans.length;a++)  {
       (function(_i, _a) {
           ***$http.get(function(){
                 console.log('i:'+_i);
                 console.log('a:'+_a);
           });***
       })(i, a);
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is Asynchronous call, you can not handle when callback will be received [AngularJs: $http Synchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603532/angularjs-http-synchronous-call)

The only way I can think of how you can handle it is that you make an array of objects and map responses to be written to correct key. After all responses would be received it can print out the array. Something like this:

```
var $scope.units = [1,2];
var $scope.shiftplans = ['plan1','plan2','plan3'];

var sizeOfResponses = $scope.units.length * $scope.shiftplans.length;
var countOfResponses = 0;
var responsesArray = [];

for(var i=0;i<$scope.units.length;i++){            
  for(var a=0;a<$scope.shiftplans.length;a++)  {
    var index = i * $scope.units.length + a;
    responsesArray[index] = {i: null, a: null
    $http.get(function(){
      responsesArray[index].i = +i;
      responsesArray[index].a = +a;
      countOfResponses++;
      if(countOfResponses === sizeOfResponses)console.log(responsesArray);
   });

 }
```

}