# Return promise in AngularJS $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-promise

I'm trying to return the values I get in my $http.get but I can't get it to work...

```
$scope.getDecision = function(id) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/decision',
        params: {id: id},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data, status, header, config) {
        console.log(data); //----> Correct values
        defer.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
        defer.reject("Something went wrong when getting decision);
    });
    return defer.promise;
};

$scope.selectView = function(id) {
     var decision = $scope.getDecision(id);
     console.log(decision); //----> undefined
}
```

When I call selectView I want to get a decision, but all I get is undefined... Have I misunderstood the promise pattern? :S

Comment: Yes, promises are still asynchronous. You cannot `return` a simple value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with asynchronous function and scope of javascript variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506970/issue-with-asynchronous-function-and-scope-of-javascript-variable)

Comment: Except for the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572), this should still log a promise object not `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http` returns a Promise anyway, so you don't really need to create your own, but the main reason this isn't working is that you still need to `.then` your `getDecision` call in order to *wait* for the asynchronous operation to complete, e.g.

```
$scope.selectView = function(id) {
     $scope.getDecision(id).then(function(decision) {
          console.log(decision);
     });
}
```

To use the existing `$http` promise:

```
$scope.getDecision = function(id) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/decision',
        params: {id: id},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`$http` itself returns a promise. No need to form your own, just do `return $http(...)`.

Comment: I removed your `.get` call since OP is using `$http` with options object, hope you don't mind :)