# Ionic Angular: ng-src chrome alert: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, google-chrome, ionic-framework

When I use **ng-src** the Google Chrome Alert:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Is it a problem?

Is there a solution?

Is there any way to make the ng-src asynchronous?

Sorry if duplicated.
Thanks.

Comment: are you fetching ng-src value from any api or service from db or backend??

Comment: @SaEChowdary ng-src get image from Controller and controller return external google maps static maps api image url.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42128191/3092596) - I had the same problem in AngularJS and it turned out to be a template name was wrong (due to a lowercase to camelCase mismatch on a case-sensitive server).