# Angular 4 - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am getting warning in console like below. And this warning coming from zone.js

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I was using Angular 2 and now I updated to Angular 4. I am also using kendo UI Angular controls. I want to know is this because of angular version update or because of my service implementation. below is service code snippet.

```
post(url: any, data: any) {


    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    try {

        return this.http.post((new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }))).do(data => {

            if (data != null && data.statusText != "No Content") {
                console.log("Response Data - ", data.json());

            }

        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know this is caused by trying to do a synchronous AJAX call from the browser. but don't know how to fix it in angular 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726860/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated-error)

Comment: @Sandman I already checked this question but it's not helpful in angular 4.

Comment: Perhaps this issue is caused by a chrome extension, I have a lot of violations in my dev tools console even when I'm doing very simple things and no XHR at all.

Comment: Was this solved?
I have something similar asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087574/how-to-make-post-calls-in-angular-4-using-observables-and-subscription)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error (*Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated...*) on my Angular 5 application due to my stupidity to try and serve the app from the source code folder instead of the *dist* folder. I make use of koa 2 on nodejs as a web server and my angular app source code is located in a folder called *public*, so I had (in *index.js* - the file run by nodejs):

```
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public'));
```

instead of:

```
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public/dist'));
```

Before starting the server I run *ng build* from the */public* folder, which builds the Angular app in */public/dist*. Point is that the cause of the error and the error message were totally unrelated.