# "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" error

Tags: ajax

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
         async: true,
         url: 'ajaxStatusDashboard.action',
         data: "status="+status+"&ageing="+ageing+"&circleName="+circleNameSelected+"&selectedYear="+yearWiseSelected,
         success: function(data){
         $("#result").html(data);
         closeModal();
         $("#result").show();
         },
         type: 'POST'
        });
```

I get this error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I am getting error like 'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726860/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated-error)