# Pass a variable between two functions in a same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I define a variable by the name `tst` in controller, and i give some value in a function by the name `GetOrders`, but when i get `tst` in another function `GetTotalValueOfProducts` it is undefined and does not have value,this is what i do:

```
<script>
 app.controller('OrderController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.quantity = 1;
    $scope.Orders = {};
    var tst ;
    GetOrders = function () {
        $http.get('/Order/GetAllOrders').success(function (response) {
            $scope.Orders = response;
            //here i set tst, and tst has value, i checked it has value and it's not undefined
            tst = response;

        });
    }
    GetOrders();

    GetTotalValueOfProducts = function () {
       //but here 'tst' is undefined!!!
        var p = tst;

    }
    GetTotalValueOfProducts();
  });
 </script>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `$http.get` is async, this will not work. You need to work with the promise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs this too

Comment: A side note:You are defining global variables GetOrders and GetTotalValueOfProducts, but I think you intend to define local functions. You can do this in two ways: (1) Insert the `var` keyword: `var GetOrders = function() { ...`, _or_ (2) Use function declaration notation: `function GetOrders () { ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because js is asynchronous.

You are executing `GetOrders()` as it is making http request, which will take time but before that http request finishes you are calling `GetTotalValueOfProducts` which makes it undefined.

```
<script>
 app.controller('OrderController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.quantity = 1;
    $scope.Orders = {};
    var tst ;

    GetTotalValueOfProducts = function () {
       //but here 'tst' is undefined!!!
        var p = tst;

    }

    GetOrders = function () {
        $http.get('/Order/GetAllOrders').success(function (response) {
            $scope.Orders = response;
            //here i set tst, and tst has value, i checked it has value and it's not undefined
            tst = response;
           GetTotalValueOfProducts();

        });
    }
    GetOrders();



  });
 </script>
```

The above should give you expected result. Not sure when you want to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Hi There AngularJS is all async so `GetTotalValueOfProducts();` is getting called before success callback return any value from http. You have to call your function once the callback is completed.

You can use $q of AngularJS to accomplish it. Here is the link [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic JavaScript async problem. Your second function is executed before the promise in the first function is resolved.

Comment: With 5k+ reputation, one would think you know what a "duplicate" is, how to mark it as such and how to vote for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
  GetTotalValueOfProducts();
```

in success callback of $http service. Change the code like this

```
  <script>
     app.controller('OrderController', function ($scope, $http) {
       $scope.quantity = 1;
       $scope.Orders = {};
       GetOrders = function () {
         $http.get('/Order/GetAllOrders').success(function (response) {
         $scope.Orders = response;
         GetTotalValueOfProducts(response)
        });
       }
      GetOrders();

      GetTotalValueOfProducts = function (tst) {
        var p = tst;
      }

     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try attaching `tst` variable into your inner `$scope` object.
**EDIT**
It was sloppy not seeing that these function are async. You should fetch your results as:

Try attaching `tst` variable into your inner `$scope` object.
EDIT
It was sloppy not seeing that these function are async. You should fetch your results as.

```
app.controller('OrderController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.quantity = 1;
  $scope.Orders = {};
  $scope.tst;
  GetOrders = function () {
      $http.get('/Order/GetAllOrders').success(function (response) {
          $scope.Orders = response;
          $scope.tst = response;
          GetTotalValueOfProducts();
      });
  }
  GetOrders();

  GetTotalValueOfProducts = function () {
     //but here 'tst' is undefined!!!
      var p = $scope.tst;
  }

});
```

Or even try to use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: The problem is the async nature of the functions, which your answer doesn't solve.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thanks for the suggestion, I had fixed my answer