# How to wait until an http request is finished before moving on?

Tags: javascript, http

I am currently accessing a database through http requests, however in the function below, i am having issues as the request is completed after the data is needed.

```
$scope.submitUserName = function() {
    console.log("button got clicked")
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/data/Graeham'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.dataStuff = response;
        console.log($scope.dataStuff);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
    console.log($scope.formData.userName);
    console.log($scope.dataStuff);

    for (var i = $scope.dataStuff.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ( $scope.formData.userName == $scope.dataStuff.data[i].ASSIGNED_TO && $scope.dataStuff.data[i].PRIMARY_UCID == "Y" ) {

            console.log($scope.dataStuff.data[i]);
            console.log($scope.dataStuff.data[i].UCID)

            $scope.assignedData.push($scope.dataStuff.data[i]);
            $scope.assignedUCID.push($scope.dataStuff.data[i].SUSPECT_UCID);

        }

    }
    console.log($scope.assignedData)
};
```

i cannot figure out what statement i need to ad to the http get to make it complete before moving onto the for loop.

Comment: Look into this question [How to $http Synchronous call with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the for loop has to be in the `successCallback` ( or in a function called from there).

Comment: I just wanted to write the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses callbacks and it's not blocking, I think you are confusing it with standard imperative code.

I don't know which framework you are using but here's your current flow:

1. main function is called
2. a GET request is issued, and the result is a Promise
3. the promise accept two parameters (`successCallback` and `errorCallback`), which are two function which will be called either in case of success or error (one of the two, not both)
4. **ERROR**: immediately after your get has been requested, you start your for loop

As @linus-borg pointed out, the for loop needs to be inside the `successCallback`, otherwise it will be called immediately after the GET request.