# AngularJS - Append to a model with a $resource

Tags: angularjs

I have this service:

```
factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/post.json', {},
        {
            query: {method:'GET', isArray: false}
        }
    );
})
```

And I have this controller:

```
function PostsCtrl($scope, Post) {
    // init
    $scope.page = 0;
    $scope.page_has_next = true;

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        if($scope.page_has_next) {
            $scope.posts = Post.query({page: ++$scope.page},
                function(data) {
                    $scope.page_has_next = data.has_next;
                }
            );
        }
    }

    $scope.loadMore();
}
```

This works just fine, each time `loadMore()` is executed the model gets updated with the next page until there are no more pages. However, I want to append the new set of posts to the current model instead of replacing it, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that posts is a array:

```
$scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(Post.query({page: ++$scope.page})
```

This will only work if the new posts has no duplicates with the old posts. If there are duplicates, you have to traverse the array and push only new posts.

Comment: It actually worked this way, I only had to initiliaze `$scope.posts = []` as an array so that the first concat would be valid. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I'm really surprised that it works as the `$resource` is asynchronous (even if it pretends to be synchronous: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11966252/1418796). The approach with the arrays contact is a good one but needs to be done in a query's callback (!).

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource this is exactly where I'm calling `concat`, in the query's callback.