# AngularJS - add data to an existing model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I built a `service`

```
.factory('Plot', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource(path, {}, {
            get: {
                method: 'GET'
                params: { myparams: params }
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Now in a `controller` I `inject` this `service` and request it like:

```
$scope.data = Plot.get(params}
```

Since I have to get new data from server, and `append` it in the `view` I need to add new data to `$scope.data`. I tried with `push` or `concat` but the `object` does not seems to be an `array` (is in fact a `$resource` `object`, I guess).
I'm new to `AngularJS` and trying to get into several mechanism, I searched for a solution but did not find anything that was my case.

I tried this: [AngularJS - Append to a model with a $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282819/angularjs-append-to-a-model-with-a-resource) but it does not seem to work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `get` will return a `promise`. Check out docs for `$q`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, `get` returns a `promise`, not an object. Easy path: you can use callback function to get returned data:

```
Plot.get(params, function(result) {
  $scope.data = result
}
```

If server returns `JSON`, then you can use syntax like `result.plot` to get nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Angularjs $resource doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

```
Usage:
$resource(url[, paramDefaults][, actions]);

Returns: A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource 
actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set contains these 
actions:

{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };

The action methods on the class object or instance  object can be invoked with the 
following parameters:

* HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])

Success callback is called with (value, responseHeaders) arguments. Error callback is 
called with (httpResponse) argument.
```

In your case:

```
Plot.get(params, successCallBack(receivedValue){ 
    \\ do something with receivedValue 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments says a promise is returned, but you don't have to wait for a successful callback.

If you want to use `$scope.data` as an array, then just initialize it as an array and append your $resource promises to it. See this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y88UB/3/

Answer (score -2):

To add data to an object:

```
var data = {}; // new object
data["someKey"] = "someValue";
```