# access element in an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a controller function as follows

```
function UserDetailsControl($scope, $routeParams, UserService) {
    $scope.user = UserService.get({id: $routeParams.id});
    alert($scope.user.phone);
}
```

When i access the user variable in templates it looks something like the following:

```
{
  "website_name": null,
  "email": "Monroe@Chamorro.com",
  "first_name": "Monroe",
  "id": "31",
  "last_name": "Chamorro",
  "phone": 2147483647,
}
```

but `alert($scope.user.phone);` this always returns `undefined`. why ? No matter what element i try to access it always returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens since the $resource is asynchronous. Check this thread for detailed explenations: [How does the $resource `get` function work synchronously in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966252/how-does-the-resource-get-function-work-synchronously-in-angularjs/11966512#11966512)