# Converting JSON element into Javascript Array in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, javascript-framework

I'm using AngularJS to make a $resource call to GET some values in JSON format.
My requirement is that I've a model element that needs a Javascript array of the form:

```
[
[1328983200000, 40],
[1328983200000, 33], 
[1328983200000, 25],
[1328983200000, 54],
[1328983200000, 26], 
[1328983200000, 25]
];
```

to be displayed in Flot charts.
This information is contained in the JSON as follows:

```
{
"marks1":15,
"marks2":20,
"dailyMarks":{
"2013-02-27T07:25:35.000+0000":40,
"2013-03-01T07:25:35.000+0000":33,
"2013-02-26T07:25:35.000+0000":25,
"2013-02-23T07:25:35.000+0000":54,
"2013-03-03T10:12:59.000+0000":26,
"2013-03-02T07:12:59.000+0000":25},
}
```

where "dailyMarks" contain the elements I need. I can convert "dailyMarks" to Javascript array, but it doesn't seem to work: (Below is my Controller code)

```
function MyController($scope, $resource) {

    var User = $resource('/marks/fetch?from=:from&to=:to', {from: inStartDate, to: inEndDate}, {
        getAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
    });

    $scope.changeDate = function(fromDate, toDate) {
        $scope.marks = User.getAll({from: fromDate, to: toDate});
    };
    var imarks = User.getAll();
    $scope.marks = imarks;

    var list = imarks.dailyMarks, arr = [];

    for (var key in list) {
        arr.push([+new Date(key), list[key]]);
    }

    $scope.myModel = arr;
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I get blank arr[] in the model. :( :(
Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `$resource` service is asynchronous even if its API might suggest that it is synchronous. This answer has more details regarding this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11966512/1418796

What you should do is to move your array post-processing to a success callback of a call to the resource, something along those lines:

```
function MyController($scope, $resource) {

    var User = $resource('/marks/fetch?from=:from&to=:to', {from: inStartDate, to: inEndDate}, {
        getAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
    });


    $scope.marks = User.getAll({from: fromDate, to: toDate}, function(marksFromServer){
      //post processing <-- goes HERE
    }
);
};
```

Other remark - you are constantly re-defining the `User` resource in a controller, you should rather move it to a factory and inject `User` to your controller.

Comment: With the code shared by me, I'm getting value in $scope.marks & can display it properly. That part is working. But I don't get anything in "myModel" Why is it so?

Comment: This is exactly the same problem of an async call. You've got this code: `var imarks = User.getAll();` which returns immediatelly with an empty array. You need to do your processing in a callback.

Comment: Oh..I see. Got it. Thanks a lot for the awesome explanation. I already spent almost 30 minutes racking my brains apart on what's wrong! Thanks a lot for showing the way!! :)

Comment: For some strange reason, the Flot Chart doesn't plot itself. :( It works when I provide static data.