# AngularJS load data before controller is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I handle loading data from a service before a page loads exactly?

I've tried to use resolve but the problem is that the service that I need to call hasn't been created yet so I would have to do all of the service logic in the resolve function, which I don't really want to do.

I currently have a working way of handling it, but of course there's the delay between when the view content is loaded and when the service has actually returned the data needed to populate:

```
myApp.service('WorkshopGetStoreState',  ['Transaction', 'ExpServices', 'CacheService', function(Transaction, ExpressServices, CacheService) {
    return {
        submit:function(defer) {
            var requestTemplate = ExpServices.getRequestTemplate('WorkshopGetStoreState');
            var request = requestTemplate.template;
            var params = {};
            params.action = "getStoreAddress";
            params.locationInfo = [{'storeId': '004141' }];
            for (var attrname in params) {
                request.service.serviceRequest[attrname] = params[attrname];
            }
            Transaction.submit(requestTemplate.url, request, defer);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.factory('WorkShopFlowService',['WorkShopGetStoreState',  function(WorkshopGetStoreState) {
    var address={};

    return {
        getStoreAddress : function() {
            return address;
        },
        setStoreAddress : function(addressParam) {
            address = addressParam;
        },
        init : function(defer){
        var promise = WorkshopGetStoreState.submit(defer);
        return promise;
    }
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('WorkshopLandingCtrl', [ '$scope', 'WorkShopFlowService', '$q', function($scope, WorkShopFlowService, $q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var storedAddress = WorkShopFlowService.getStoreAddress();
    if (storedAddress) {
        $scope.address = storedAddress; 
    }
    else {
        WorkShopFlowService.getDefaultLocation(defer).then(function(result) {
        $scope.address = result.serviceResponse.storeInfo[0];
        WorkShopFlowService.setStoreAddress($scope.address);
        });
    }
}]);
```

**Edit:** It seems that there is now support for referencing objects as string names in the newer version of AngularJS so now doing it in a resolve is the way to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to delay showing anything until you have data? There are better ways to do that.

Comment: Just the dynamic data from the service. I know there's a couple ways of going about this, but i'm sure there's a simple "best practice" for this.

Comment: As @JimCote alluded too, if you're just trying to delay showing something, I'd set the opacity of your view to 0, then use ng-class to show your view once the data is resolved. `ng-class="{in:address}` where "in" class sets the opacity to 1.

Comment: Off topic, but you may find it cleaner to declare your defer in the service and return the promise the same way. Then you can just do `WorkShopFlowService.init().then(etc..` and delete the first few lines of your controller. Mostly a preference thing, but if you do this a lot it'll save you some code.

Comment: Have you considered calling a function on the service to "get" the data in an angular run block?  I think those are executed pretty early on.

Comment: I agree with jonathan, promises are probably the right answer. However take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966252/how-does-the-resource-get-function-work-synchronously-in-angularjs  $resources instantly return an empty value, but then when the async completes they apply the data to 'your' variable in the background

Comment: I have considered the run block, but this isn't the entry point for the application itself, it will just be a service called on the landing of a certain path. I like that idea of using the class, i'll give that a whirl but is there a functional way to make this synchronous in any way?