# why is arr.length is returning 0, for an array called through angular-resource query method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried accessing `db.json` file which contains an array of quotes, through angular-resource method :

`var arr = $resource(baseUrl+"quotes/:id").query()`

But when i tried printing the length of this array using :

```
console.log(arr.length)
```

Its returning 0, where as `console.log(arr)` is returning my array correctly

Comment: What exactly is console.log(arr) printing out for you?

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966252/how-does-the-resource-get-function-work-synchronously-in-angularjs), this behavior is well covered in [the documentation for $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).